# Change the Date box display format in jtsage date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

Hi i need to Change the [jstage Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) Date box display format like day-month-year in UI ( Black display date box field ) not in html text.

That is first day, after month, after year should be displayed in datebox. Is that possible. how?

Second one is time box when click the plus icon in time need to increase the time value to 15 minutes (currently the value is increased by 1 minute like 10:01 ,  10:02 i want 10:15 , 10:30). :)

currently able to change the header format

```
<div data-role="content">
        <label for="mydate">Some Date</label> <input name="mydate"
            id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
            data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideHeaderFormat": "%d.%m.%Y"}' />
    </div>
```

Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/FwRsq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is updated fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwRsq/4/)

```
 <input data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox","dateFieldOrder":["d","m","y"], "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat": "%d.%m.%Y"}'  name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date"/>

 <input data-role='datebox' data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideTimeFormat": "24","minuteStep": 15}' name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date"/>
```

Comment: when i click the plus icon for minutes need to increse 0, 15,30,45 not  1,2,3......

Comment: any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653524/jquery-mobile-date-picker-not-shown-in-popup

Comment: i see its answered :)

Comment: any suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430461/how-to-show-only-before-dates-in-jtsage-date-picker

Answer (score 1):

For the time increment, use the `minuteStep` option:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role='datebox' data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideTimeFormat": "24", "minuteStep": 15}' />
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/FwRsq/7/)**