# Jquery mobile date picker not shown in popup field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I used `jtsage jquery mobile date picker`. I want to show the date picker when click the text inside popup but the date picker shown in back side of the popup i want to show the date picker infront of the popup.

My code is like.

```
<div data-role="content">

        <a data-rel="popup" href="#datepop">POPUP</a>
        <div id="datepop" class='ui-content' data-role='popup'>
        <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Refer this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/tZtMR/1/

Comment: Sry I don't understand what is that you want? You said date picker is showing behind popup (which is correct) but then you need it behind same popup (its already there). Do you need it in front of popup?

Comment: @Gajotres sorry infront of popup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zV3jU/

#### CSS:

```
.ui-datebox-container {
    z-index: 500000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: it is working fine ..in my mobile the data picker doesn't close after set date.

Comment: what mobile phone are you using? I have tested this on desktop and mobile chrome (Samsung S4)

Comment: i am using this in phonegap application.I tested in my enulator..wait i will check in device.Thank you +1. Accept another 5 mins.

Comment: WOrking well in my device. Thank you so much.

Comment: any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778652/not-able-to-close-the-jt-sage-date-picker-after-pick-date