# How to show only before dates in JTSAGE date picker

Tags: javascript, date, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

I use [Jtsage](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)  date picker in my mobile application(jquery mobile and phonegap). I want to show only today and before today date(`hide future dates` ) so i refer this [documentaion](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/opt/limit.html). In that documentation they mention **afterToday,beforeToday,notToday,minDays,maxDays**. I use `beforeToday` for my `datebox` but it seems not working.
My date picker calling is like:

```
 <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"afterToday":false,"beforeToday":true,"maxDays": 1}'/>
```

refer this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ktbcP/436/)

Comment: you mean ,,, future dates should not be selectable in date picker.

Comment: @Dave yes i don't want to select future dates..

Comment: is it ok to do with calendar box... see future date is restricted,, or u want with datebox only http://jsfiddle.net/ktbcP/437/

Comment: @Dave i want with datebox (not calbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add an event to catch the 'set'. If date being set is in the future, popup a message and stopImmediatePropagation:

```
$('#mydate').on('datebox', function (event, payload) {
    if (payload.method === 'set') {
        var startdate = new Date();
        if (payload.date > startdate) {
            window.alert('You cannot select future dates!');
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
   }
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ktbcP/442/)**

Comment: any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280308/how-to-disable-the-already-selected-date-for-next-date-box-in-j-t-sage-date-pick